# mapping network drive with Array

Tags: arrays, vbscript, for-loop, wsh

Problem is on line (objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive CStr(colDrives.Item(i)), CStr(newMappingArray(j)), TRUE), where my script actually attempts to reconnect the network drive. it fails because it doesnt detect it as a string?

i attempted to use the same code just with "" around the path and drive letter and it works so im not sure where to go from here..

CODE DESCRIPTION
it takes a list of share names, checks if any of the remote paths are mapped to drives. IF they are then it goes through them. unmaps them, uses the same drive letter and remaps them using the new path reference(with currently logged in credentials..

code below

```
On Error Resume Next

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' ARRAY SETUP '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
DIM oldMappingArray(5)
oldMappingArray(0) = "\\DDCSHRNASP02\u_amr_project"
oldMappingArray(1) = "\\DDCSHRNASP02\U_AMS_Deployment"
oldMappingArray(2) = "\\DDCSHRNASP02\u_corp_share"
oldMappingArray(3) = "\\DDCSHRNASP02\u_dcwb_control_room"
oldMappingArray(4) = "\\DDCSHRNASP02\u_dis"
oldMappingArray(5) = "\\DDCSHRNASP02\u_dis15"

oldMappingArrayLength = UBound(oldMappingArray)


DIM newMappingArray(5)
newMappingArray(0) = "\\EUCPRDNAS02\u_amr_project"
newMappingArray(1) = "\\EUCPRDNAS02\U_AMS_Deployment"
newMappingArray(2) = "\\EUCPRDNAS02\u_corp_share"
newMappingArray(3) = "\\EUCPRDNAS02\u_dcwb_control_room"
newMappingArray(4) = "\\EUCPRDNAS02\u_dis"
newMappingArray(5) = "\\EUCPRDNAS02\u_dis15"

newMappingArrayLength = UBound(newMappingArray)


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' WMI SETUP '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
Set colDrives = objNetwork.EnumNetworkDrives
colDrivesLength = colDrives.count
wscript.echo colDrivesLength

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' MAIN LOOP '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
For i=0 to colDrivesLength-1 Step 2
    'Gets every other in the array, making i equal to a PATH
wscript.echo i
For j=0 to oldMappingArrayLength
    'count through all of the old path names
    wscript.echo j
    wscript.echo "Drive Letter = " + colDrives.Item(i) 'Drive letter
    wscript.echo "Current Path = " + colDrives.Item(i+1) 'Path of the Drive Above

    wscript.echo "Tested Path = " + oldMappingArray(j) 'Path Currently Testing

    if colDrives.Item(i+1) = oldMappingArray(j) then
        'If the drive path from enumeration is equal to the old drive mapping array...
        wscript.echo "Item being added -> " + colDrives.Item(i)
        wscript.echo "to be mapped ---> " + newMappingArray(j)

        objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive colDrives.Item(i), True, True
        WScript.sleep 3000 'Wait 1.0 seconds
        objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive CStr(colDrives.Item(i)), CStr(newMappingArray(j)), TRUE
        exit For 'ends the oldMappingArrayLength loop if a match was found
    End If
Next
Next

Set objNetwork = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test it out, this seems a timetaking and complicated process for mapping driveletters so i'm not going to break my head with it but the wscript.echo "to be mapped ---> " + newMappingArray(j) must be the culpit. The + is no concatenation on VbScript but the & is.

So everywhere you use + it should become &

You could shorten your script by using the following way to build your array

```
oldMappingArray = ("u_amr_project", "U_AMS_Deployment", ...)
```

and then if you need the whole string use

```
"\\DDCSHRNASP02\" & oldMappingArray(j)
```

Comment: haha alright im used to PHP, so yeah. I am only using the echo's so i can see output in my file while i run it. I commended out that line and it still didnt work.

I like the idea of shortening the array like that, but there really are hundreds of servers and shares we are testing, i shortened the script for this purpose. 

However i think the whole string is the problem, because if i put in a string in the code for adding, then it works for mapping the drive.

Comment: hmm, sometimes you have to assign the contents of an array to a variable first, don't ask me why, it's these thing that drive me away from vbscript, most of the time i program in Ruby now, that's fun. So try mapping = newMappingArray(j):drive = colDrives.item(i):objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive drive, mapping, TRUE

Comment: ok so that is seperate lines...got it. though it didnt make any difference. I can echo out the variables and everything is all right. just when it is passed into the MapNetworkDrive function it no longer works. sooo frustrating.

Comment: what is the err.description after that line ? try first met non persistent (leave the thirds paramater) See http://ss64.com/vb/syntax-drivemap.html for a good example

Comment: the error i get is the following, WSHNetwork.MapNetworkDrive: A device attached to the system is not functioning.

so like the linked script do you recommend me attempting to remove the reg files?

Comment: after the objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive you should check if the mapping is still there (first manual, later in the script), if you'r sure it is gone, then try mapping it manual, then try it in the script. In such cases split your script in small steps and try each of they manually under the same conditions